# If $S\to T$ is a closed immersion, then $X\times_S Y\simeq X\times_T Y$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, universal-property, fibre-product

> Let $X,Y$ be $S$-schemes and $S\to T$ a closed immersion of schemes. Prove that we have a natural $T$-isomorphism $X\times_S Y\simeq X\times_T Y$.

Let $f:X\to S$ and $g:Y\to S$ the structural morphisms and $h:S\to T$ the closed immersion. We immetiately that $X,Y$ are also $T$-schemes with structure morphisms $h\circ f,h\circ g$ respectively. Also $X\times_S Y$ has a $T$-scheme structure via $(x,y)\mapsto h\circ f(x)=h\circ g(y)$.

We have the natural $T$-morphisms $p_T:X\times_T Y\to X,q_T:X\times_T Y\to Y$ as well as $p_S:X\times_S Y\to X$ and $p_S:X\times_S Y\to X$ as well as $\pi:X\times_T Y\to T$ given by $(x,y)\mapsto h\circ f(x)=h\circ g(y)$.

By the universal property, we have a unique morphism $\varphi:X\times_S Y\to X\times_T Y$ with $p_T\circ \varphi=p_S$ and $q_T\circ \varphi=q_S$.

But I don't know how to prove $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

Set theoretically, we see that $X\times_S Y=X\times_T Y$, since $f(x)=g(y)\Leftrightarrow h\circ f(x)=h\circ g(y)$ by injectivity of $h$, so it's natural to presume an ismorphism, but that's far from showing $\varphi$ is an isomorphism.

How do I do that?

Comment: By the way: you seem to be making an (understandable) error in your post. (First, I think you want $g$ to be the structural morphism $Y \to S$.) The topological ("set-theoretic") points of $X \times_{S} Y$ are not pairs $(x, y)$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$, unfortunately: the description is more complicated. What IS true is that for any scheme $Z$, the scheme-theoretic points $(X \times_{S} Y)(Z)$ are exactly given by the fiber product $X(Z) \times_{S(Z)} Y(Z)$.

Comment: Whato do you mean by $X(Z)$?

Comment: $X(Z)$ is the set of morphisms of schemes $Z \to X$. You can read more about this in section 6.3.7 of Vakil (referenced below), for example.

Comment: @AlexWertheim about the characterization of $X\times_S Y$ as pairs $(x,y)$ with $f(x)=g(y)$, at least does it work when $X,Y,S$ are affine schemes?

Comment: I'm afraid not. Consider $S = \mathrm{Spec}(\mathbb{Z}), X = Y = \mathbb{A}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}$. Then one may check that $X \times_{S} Y \cong \mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{Z}}$, but the points of $\mathbb{A}^{2}_{\mathbb{Z}}$ cannot be interpreted as pairs of points of $\mathbb{A}^{1}_{\mathbb{Z}}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't think one even needs that $h$ is a closed immersion - I believe this is true whenever $h$ is a monomorphism, and any closed immersion is a monomorphism. (See, e.g., [here](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04XV).)

The point is that when $h$ is a monomorphism, the fiber products $X \times_{S} Y$ and $X \times_{T} Y$ satisfy the same universal property. Given maps $u \colon Z \to X, v \colon Z \to Y$ such that the compositions $Z \to X \to S, Z \to Y \to S$ agree, then clearly, the compositions $Z \to X \to S \to T, Z \to Y \to S \to T$ agree. (As you've observed, this is what gives you the universal map $\varphi \colon X \times_{S} Y \to X \times_{T} Y$).

On the other hand, if $u, v$ are such that the compositions $Z \to X \to S \to T, Z \to Y \to S \to T$ agree, then $Z \to X \to S, Z \to Y \to S$ agree by cancellation. This gives you the universal map $X \times_{T} Y \to X \times_{S} Y$ which is inverse to your map $\varphi$.

Comment: (Incidentally, this is exercise 1.3X in Vakil's wonderful "Foundations of Algebraic Geometry". Definitely worth a read!)